# Why does my function in Unix shell always return 0?

Tags: function, shell, unix, ksh

In my script bkp_hot-routes.ksh I want to test return code of a mv command by using a function that displays OK or WARN (function check_return_warn).

Problem is return code is always 0 even if I delete source file before the mv.

**Script bkp_hot-routes.ksh**

```
#Load functions
export FPATH=/app/rl/exploit/functions
${FPATH}/init

rm ${HRFILE}
mv ${HRFILE} ${HRFILE}"_"${DATE_TAG}
check_return_warn "${MSG_ETAPE} : Horodatage du fichier des HR (commande mv)"
```

**Init file**

```
#!/bin/ksh

init()
{
        for file in `ls -1 $FPATH`
        do
                . ${FPATH}/$file
        done
}
```

**check_return_warn file**

```
#!/bin/ksh
check_return_warn ()
{
RCwritelog=$?
ETAP_NOM=$1
MSG_ERR=$(echo "$2" | tr '\n' ' ')

if [ ${RCwritelog} -ne 0 ]; then
   log_write_warn "${ETAP_NOM} : Echec. ${MSG_ERR}" "${RCwritelog}"
else
   log_write_ok "${ETAP_NOM} : Termin▒ avec succ▒s."
fi
return ${RCwritelog}
}
```

In debug we see that test is always : *if [ 0 -ne 0 ]; then*

All functions are in the same directory : /app/rl/exploit/functions

Other functions do not have this problem.
check_return_warn has been created by copying check_return_error which has the same code except a log_write_error call instead of log_write_warn
If I use check_return_error to test the KO of the mv, return code is <> 0

Can you please have a look ? Thank you

David

Comment: Can't seem to be able to reproduce that problem using your code. That said, $? contains the return code of the last action, to be sure my function is processing the "right one" I would pass the value along the other parameter to the function right after the move instead of checking the value within the function....just my 2 cents

Comment: Agree with above, to make it explicit, I would do `.... mv ${HRFILE} ${HRFILE}"_"${DATE_TAG}; mvRc=$?; check_return_warn "$mvRc" ""${MSG_ETAPE} : Horodatage ...."` and fix check_return_warn to accept a "$1" value for the `mvRC` value.. Good luck.

Comment: What is `mv`?  Perhaps `mv` is not `/bin/mv` but is some shell wrapper.

Comment: Try debugging. Write `mvRc=$?;echo "After mv: ${mvRc}" ` directly after the move before callig the check function. When `mv`seems to give a fixed return value, isolate the command by deleting the `${FPATH}/init` of calling it from the command line.